# Assert on something which may not be there - nullreferenceexception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

Using nUnit.  result is a ViewResult coming back from an MVC3 controller - it may or may not be there.

This works, but smells!  Is there a better way?

```
        string errorMessage = "";
        try {
            errorMessage = result.TempData["Error"].ToString();
        }
        catch {}
        Assert.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage);
```

UPDATE1
Getting closer... but can't get the right error message out of the test as shown below:
[image]

UPDATE2:
Refactored to this:

```
        string errorMessage = "";
        if (result != null)
            errorMessage = result.TempData["Error"].ToString();
        Assert.IsEmpty(errorMessage);
```

UPDATE3:
in response to @Peri

```
 public void new_trick_should_be_saved_without_error() {
        var controller = new TricksController();
        var formCollection = new FormCollection() {
                                                    { "Name", "asdf" },
                                                    { "Description", "test descr"},
                                                    { "Votes", "4" }
                                                  };
        var result = controller.Create(formCollection) as ViewResult;

        string errorMessage = "";
        if (result != null)
            errorMessage = result.TempData["Error"].ToString();
        Assert.IsEmpty(errorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with your test if you have to test if result != null.

Comment: Possibly.. have put in Update 3 above.

Comment: Why does Create return ViewResult or sth else? Based on those values in FormCollection shouldn't it always return ViewResult or always sth else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to a try/catch.

You are testing for null, not that there is an empty string.

```
Assert.IsNull(result.TempData["Error"])
```

or

```
if (result != null && result.TempData["Error"] != null) errorMessage = result.TempData["Error"].ToString();
Assert.IsEmpty(errorMessage )
```

Comment: Cheer @Valamas - have added a screenshot with 3 different cases above.

Comment: result is null. Have updated my answer. However, I advise a static function to GetErrorMessage(Result result). You can place null checks in there and always have it return at the very least, a empty or null string. Makes it simpler to test and more readable.

Comment: Thanks again @Valamas - am going for simplicity in current code, so took out a check and put in code above.  Thanks for suggestion on static fn.